# Binding parameters with spring jpa native query for postgresql jsonb oeprators

Tags: postgresql, jpa, indexing, jsonb

I have created an index on a field in jsonb column:

```
CREATE INDEX ON Employee USING gin((properties -> 'hobbies'))
```

'hobbies' is a top level field in properties column and has structure as:

```
"hobbies": [
        "cooking", "trekking"
    ]
```

Running following in pgadmin works:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE (e.properties -> 'hobbies') @> '["trekking"]'
```

Now, I want to integrate it with Spring repository but I am not able to get it working. I tried with:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE (e.properties -> 'hobbies') @> :jsonSearchString)", nativeQuery = true )
```

....passing jsonSearchString as

```
[\""+hobby+"\"]
```

...where hobby is input.

What change I would need here?

Comment: Did you try `cast(:jsonSearchString as jsonb)`?

Comment: Yes, I tried with ...WHERE (e.properties -> 'hobbies') @> CAST(:jsonSearchString as jsonb). This also doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error you get? How exactly are you building the search string? Can you [edit] your question and add the relevant Java code? (It looks as if you are escaping the double quotes)